Weird cp behaviour when script is executed from systemd
I have a script that behaves weirdly when executed from systemd if I use cp instead of cat.
My script:
#!/bin/bash
steamcmd +login anonymous +app_info_update 1 +app_info_print 3017300 +quit | grep -Po '(?<=number : ).*(?=/)' > /home/sunyata/steamsrv/soulmaskDIY/versioncheck.txt 
while true; do

    check=$(cat /home/sunyata/steamsrv/soulmaskDIY/versioncheck.txt)
    number=$(cat /home/sunyata/steamsrv/soulmaskDIY/versioncurrent.txt)
    timestamp=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
    if [ "$check" = "$number" ];then
        echo "No update, checked version $check remains same as previous version $number, updatecheck done at $timestamp" >> /home/sunyata/steamsrv/soulmaskDIY/serverlog
    sync
        exit
    else
        echo "New update available version $check, previous was $number, initiating restart to apply update at $timestamp" >> /home/sunyata/steamsrv/soulmaskDIY/serverlog
        cat /home/sunyata/steamsrv/soulmaskDIY/versioncheck.txt > /home/sunyata/steamsrv/soulmaskDIY/versioncurrent.txt
    sync
        exit
    fi


When I use cp /home/sunyata/steamsrv/soulmaskDIY/versioncheck.txt /home/sunyata/steamsrv/soulmaskDIY/versioncurrent.txt  instead of cat the output looks like this;
New update available version , previous was 24503527, initiating restart to apply update at 2024-07-28_15-26-37

New update available version 24503527, previous was , initiating restart to apply update at 2024-07-28_15-41-38

One time, the versioncheck.txt file is empty; the other time, the versioncurrent.txt file is empty.
cp and also cat work perfectly when executed manually, the issue is only present when the script is with cp and run with systemd:
Type=oneshot
User=sunyata
WorkingDirectory=/home/sunyata/steamsrv/soulmaskDIY/
Environment="LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/sunyata/steamsrv/soulmaskDIY/"
ExecStart=bash /home/sunyata/steamsrv/soulmaskDIY/autoupdatesteamsg1.sh

It works perfect with cat, but I would like to understand why cp isnt working here? Can't systemd handle cp inside scripts?

It needs to be clarified what the issue is. What does "isn't working" mean? What would you want to happen if either of the files is empty when the script is run? What initiates the contents of the versioncheck.txt file?

Your while loop is run only once, because the exit in each flow from the if statement ends code execution

In addition to @Chris’s comments:  (1) Please indent code properly.  (2) I recommend that you do check_file=/home/sunyata/steamsrv/soulmaskDIY/versioncheck.txt and current_file=/home/sunyata/steamsrv/soulmaskDIY/versioncurrent.txt (and maybe also the server log file) and then use the variables in the commands.  (3) Add ls -ld "$check_file" "$current_file" before and after the cp command and tell us what it tells you.  (4) Your script suggests that some other process or mechanism is modifying one or both of the files.  Tell us about that. … (Cont’d)

(Cont’d) …  (5) Is it always 24503527, or does the number change?  (5a) Does that number have any significance that you aren’t telling us?  (6) Why does your script end with ...?

what alot of questions. meanwhile ive made a seperate script to ensure the versioncheck.txt gets filled with same data everytime it gets written. So far it seems that is correct. So the weird behaviour is still the same, and more verified now. The command which writes data to versioncheck.txt is;  steamcmd +login anonymous  +app_info_update 1 +app_info_print 3017300 +quit | grep -Po '(?<=number : ).*(?=/)' > /home/sunyata/steamsrv/soulmaskDIY/versioncheck.txt

I will try to edit this post with more info and make it more clear, and also try all your suggestions and inform you about the outputs

Your script won't do anything because it will fail with an unclosed while loop

this can be closed, i found out that the output from the command that sets the variable sometimes returns empty.
